# How to convert object into array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below object obj(coming as a JSON response):

```js
var obj = {
  0: {
    note: 'test1',
    id: 24759045,
    createTimeStamp: '2022-08-01T17:05:36.750Z',
  },
  1: {
    note: 'test2',
    id: 24759045,
    createTimeStamp: '2022-08-01T17:05:51.755Z',
  },
  note: 'test1',
  id: 24759045,
  createTimeStamp: '2022-08-01T17:05:36.750Z',
};
```

I only want the objects with numbers("0" , "1" .. so on) to be pushed in an array.

Below is what I am trying to do:

```js
let items = [];
for (var prop in obj) {
  items.push(obj[prop]);
}
console.log(items);
```

// expected output:

```
[
  {
    note: 'test1',
    id: 24759045,
    createTimeStamp: '2022-08-01T17:05:36.750Z',
  },
  {
    note: 'test2',
    id: 24759045,
    createTimeStamp: '2022-08-01T17:05:51.755Z',
  },
]
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So your code seems to be working. What is the question?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => !Number.isNaN(parseInt(key))).map((key) => obj[key]))`

Answer (score 2):

A few things to consider here.

- Are the numeric keys ordered?
- Does the order matter?
- Are the numeric keys an index of the item in the array?
- Are there any gaps in the numeric keys?

First solution, assuming that the numeric keys are the index in the array.

```js
const items = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  const index = parseInt(key);
  if (Number.isNaN(index)) {
    return acc;
  }
  acc[index] = obj[key];
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Second solution, assuming that order matters, but that the numeric keys are not guaranteed to be contiguous.

```js
const items = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter((key) => Number.isNaN(parseInt(key)) === false)
  .sort()
  .map((key) => obj[key]);
```

Keep in mind that Object.keys does not guarantee that the keys are ordered alpha-numerically. So if order matters, then you have to sort them.

Third solution, if order doesn't matter.

```js
const items = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter((key) => Number.isNaN(parseInt(key)) === false)
  .map((key) => obj[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = [];

var obj = {
  "0": {
    "note": "test1",
    "id": 24759045,
    "createTimeStamp": "2022-08-01T17:05:36.750Z"
  },
  "1": {
    "note": "test2",
    "id": 24759045,
    "createTimeStamp": "2022-08-01T17:05:51.755Z"
  },
  "note": "test1",
  "id": 24759045,
  "createTimeStamp": "2022-08-01T17:05:36.750Z"
}


for (var i in obj)
  result.push(obj[i]);

$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

You can achieve this by doing the following steps.

Copied your object below -->

```
var obj = {
  "0": {
    "note": "test1",
    "id": 24759045,
    "createTimeStamp": "2022-08-01T17:05:36.750Z"
  },
  "1": {
    "note": "test2",
    "id": 24759045,
    "createTimeStamp": "2022-08-01T17:05:51.755Z"
  },
  "note": "test1",
  "id": 24759045,
  "createTimeStamp": "2022-08-01T17:05:36.750Z"
}
```

Created new js array -->

```
var result = [];
```

Code -->

```
for (var i in obj)
  result.push(obj[i]);
```

Find the solution from link below as well --> :) :)

https://jsfiddle.net/kavinduxo/95qnpaed/

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll need to get the keys of the object, filter out the non-numeric ones, then map each key to the obj[key]:

```js
var obj={"0":{"note":"test1","id":24759045,
"createTimeStamp":"2022-08-01T17:05:36.750Z"},"1":{"note":"test2","id":24759045,
"createTimeStamp":"2022-08-01T17:05:51.755Z"},
"note":"test1","id":24759045,"createTimeStamp":"2022-08-01T17:05:36.750Z"};

console.log(
    Object.keys(obj)
          .filter((key) =>!Number.isNaN(parseInt(key)))
          .map((key) => obj[key])
)
```